# Query returns no result, but returns results when executed manually

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a very weird issue: when I execute a simple query manually on the database, I get the expected results. When I run it using a PHP script, I get no results.

My code:

```
class Database {

    private static function connect() {
        return new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name", 'db_user', 'db_password');
    }

    public static function findAllCategories() {
        $pdo = Database::connect();

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories");
        if (!$stmt) {
            printf("Query failed: %s\n", $pdo->error);
            exit;
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }

}
```

The code above yields no results when I call it from a script using `Database::findAllCategories()`, but when I execute the query manually (using phpmyadmin, running on localhost), I get all categories in that table.

I have no idea why there's a difference in results. As far as I can see, there are no exceptions and I'm 100% sure that the query gets executed on the same machine and database. What could this be?

Comment: but what it does return? what is output if `var_dump(Database::findAllCategories());` ?

Comment: Check if connecting to database. Try to throw error if  not connected to database

Comment: I just found the solution myself, but thanks for your thoughts anyway!

Comment: Would you kindly add your solution for others to find if you think it is applicable to others. If not, then just a comment, please.

Comment: I have added the answer already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, as soon as you post the question, you get a great idea about what could possibly cause the issue... :)

It seems that my `db_user` somehow lost its privileges on the database `db_name`. While I would expect that I would get an 'access denied' exception, it didn't happen and just returned an empty array. I granted the necessary privileges to the user and it works.

Comment: The whole point was that no error was thrown, the query just returned an empty array.

Comment: query returned empty array -> as the user don't have privilege to select the db  -> as the error message was not there while connection to the db. It is bad practice of coding in the first step itself

Comment: That is true, I haven't gotten this far with my development though. Thanks for the suggestion.